# Jest unit tests not working with third party node module

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Jest unit tests not working with third party node module.

I'm finding it hard to mock this third party npm module that I use all over my app.

**Tech stack**: jest, angular v12 and typescript.

The third party npm thats causing issues is:

import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';

(Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions)

**My unit test:**

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended';

import { InteractiveModalComponent } from './interactive-modal.component';
import { GoogleService } from '../../../services';

describe('InteractiveModalComponent', () => {
  let component: InteractiveModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<InteractiveModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [InteractiveModalComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [{ provide: NgxPermissionsService, useValue: mock<NgxPermissionsService>() }, GoogleService],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InteractiveModalComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should equal true', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**My component that I'm trying to start testing:**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { GoogleService } from '../../../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'interactive-modal-view',
  templateUrl: './interactive-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./interactive-modal.component.scss'],
})
export class InteractiveModalComponent {
  @Output() close = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(private googleService: GoogleService) {}

  private sendEvent(): void {
    this.googleService.send('test');
  }

  navigate(): void {
    this.close.emit();
  }
}
```

**My error:**

[image]

**jest-config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: [
    "<rootDir>",
  ],
  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec).+(ts)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage/test',
};
```

**Permission service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';

import { UtilityService } from '.';

@Injectable()
export class PermissionService {
  constructor(private utilityService: UtilityService, private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService) {}

  public setPermission(roles: object): void {
    const permissions = this.utilityService.mapRoles(roles);
    this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(permissions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code of `permission.service.ts`.

Comment: @Benny permission service added.

Comment: Try the following in your test file: first `import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended';`  inside `providers: []` array, add an entry `{ provide: NgxPermissionsService, useValue: mock<NgxPermissionsService>() }`

Comment: Thanks @Benny for looking into this issue for me.
I got an error with your changes. I've updated the code attempt above and the new error message in a screenshot.

Comment: how about reinstalling `npx-permissions`? Maybe the package is not installed successfully. Also, maybe you need `imports: [NgxPermissionsModule]` too

Comment: I've tried both those and got same error:  Cannot find module 'ngx-permissions' from 'src/app/shared/components/interactive-modal/interactive-modal.component.spec.ts'

Comment: Read here https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/04/how-to-fix-the-cannot-find-module-when-importing-components-with-absolute-paths-with-jest/. It may be helpful

Comment: @Benny I've read the article and updated the: jest-config.js like above. But still get the same error:  Cannot find module 'ngx-permissions' from 'src/app/services/permission.service.ts'

Comment: Enigma. This is the time to create a Stackblitz project that will reproduce your problem. Then others like me may be able to make changes and hopefully fix.